# EF4 CTP4 Get Poco Entity Instead of Proxy Object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have a proxy entity but I want to save the poco entity to the session

Comment: Are you sure you're using CTP4? The official release was nearly 5 months ago.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 5 months ago? ctp4 is from july. Is there a ctp5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have you got your solution setup for generated POCO objects?  If not, you should read this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) and this article on using the [POCO Generator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Once you have, make sure you turn of the use of proxies when you use a DataContext.  Can you provide more information about your solution?

Example of disabling Proxy Generation:

```
// Disable proxy object creation.
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```